# Silverlight: Why does this style work in one place but not another?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a style in my `Application.Resources`:

```
    <Style x:Name="TransparentBackground" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AntiqueWhite" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".6" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    </Style>
```

I have applied it in two places. In the first, it works:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource TransparentBackground}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name, FallbackValue='File Name'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <Run Text="." Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />
                    <Run Text="{Binding TypeExtension, FallbackValue='type'}" Foreground="#787878" FontWeight="Light" />
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When I that `DataTemplate` is rendered, it looks great. However, when I use the style within `LayoutRoot`, it fails:

```
        <Border Style="{StaticResource TransparentBackground}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="searchResultsFoundCountText" />
        </Border>
```

The background color is grey instead of `AntiqueWhite`, and the opacity is `1` instead of `.6`. However, the padding seems to be working. Why might this be happening?

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set properties using style setter. This way has a small priority (8th place).

1. Set by coercion by the property system.
2. Set by active animations or held animations.
3. Set locally, either by code, by direct setting in XAML, or through data binding.
4. Set by the TemplatedParent.
5. Implicit style—this applies only to the Style property.
6. Set by Style triggers.
7. Set by Template triggers.
8. Set by Style setters.
9. Set by the default Style.
10. Set by inheritance.
11. Set by metadata

But you have a silverlight without triggers and your code doesn't contain templates, so a possible answer may be code setter (3rd) or animation (2nd).

Also your style works well in the root user control MainPage.xaml.

Here is [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28VS.85%29.aspx) about property precendence.

Comment: I don't think that I'm doing anything about #8 in that list. But I guess I'll check more thoroughly. What is "coercion by the property system" or "implicit style"?

Comment: I have attached msdn link with detailed information to my answer. 1st item means "Coercion allows you to control the final value that is set on the DP via the CoerceValueCallback assigned in the DP’s PropertyMetaData. It is a programmatic way of constraining the value of the DP.". The simpliest way for checking a binding is using code Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}" where converter doesn't do anything, it is intended for putting a breakpoint inside it.